# SQL: Consolidating results

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am a relative beginner in SQL (Learned and forgotten many times) and entirely self taught so please excuse my likely lack of proper terminology. I made a query that pulls items that have been returned, each items' row has a return code. Here is a result sample:

[image: Result Sample]

In the final report(Created with Visual Studio), I would like to be able to have a count of returns by return type but I would need to consolidate the 40 or so return codes into 4 or 5 return type groups. So RET_CODE values ) and . are both product quality issues and would count in the "Product Quality" row.

I could use some help with what the best way to accomplish this would be.

Thank You

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The bad way!**

You could do this by creating the grouping within your SQL statement with something like

```
SELECT 
        *, 
        CASE 
             WHEN RET_CODE IN ('.', ')') THEN 'Quality Error'
             WHEN RET_CODE IN ('X', 'Y', 'Z') THEN 'Some Other error'
             ELSE [Desc1]
        END AS GroupDescription 
      FROM myTable
```

The problem with this approach is that you have to keep repeating it every time you want to something similar.

---

**The better option.** (but not perfect!)

Assuming you do not already have such a table...

Create a table that contains the grouping. You can use this in the future whenever you need to do this kind of thing.

For example.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyErrorGroupTable (RET_CODE varchar(10), GroupDescription varchar(50))
INSERT INTO dbo.MyErrorGroupTable VALUES
    ('.', 'Quality Error'),
    (')', 'Quality Error'),
    ('X', 'Some Other Error'),
    ('Y', 'Some Other Error'),
    ('.', 'Some Other Error'),
    ('P', 'UPS Error'),
    ('A', 'PAck/Pick Error')
```

etc....

Then you can simply join to this table and use the `GroupDescription` in your report

e.g.

```
SELECT 
    a.*, b.GroupDescription
    FROM myTable a 
        JOIN MyErrorGroupTable b ON a.RET_CODE = b.RET_CODE
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: This is not an answer. If your not going to provide a solution or explain why GROUP BY is a possible solution you should make this a comment on the Question.

Comment: Yea, I thought GROUP BY would be what would do it, but how do I consolidate the different return codes into groups? I would want all rows with return codes a,b,c,h,5,7,0, to count into one "custom group" and return codes d,e,f,g,1,2 to be counted into the row of another "custom group".

Comment: Funny. I composed an entire GROUP BY solution but pulled it back because (a) OP could have tried harder with SQL syntax before coming here and (b) OP could learn more by investigating GROUP BY syntax than by being spoon fed the answer. Alan fed a man a fish. I was trying to get him to learn about fishing.